# Display Specifc rows based on column values

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

My report currently looks like this.

```
Customer----Jobcode1----Jobcode2----Jobcode3----Jobcode4

Abcxyz10----01234567---tuyytkjkjkjj-----yuiyuiyuiu----nmncdnmc

Abczyz11----kjlkjasdljd----01234567-----sddfsdffdsf---01234567

Abcxyz12----askjaklsjd----acsddfccf------asdrfr4455----sackjkcc

Abcxyz13----skdfjjdskf-----12323333-----asdafeffrfrr----isduiodiid
```

There are 4 rows and 5 columns, namely: `Customer`, `Jobcode1`, `Jobcode2`, `Jobcode3`, `Jobcode4`.

I want to display only those rows for which any of the 4 `jobcode` values are `01234567`.

So for the above data only the first two rows should be displayed.

Please let me know how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter:**

```
'01234567' in ([Jobcode1],[Jobcode2],[Jobcode3],[Jobcode4])
```